# HTML Table with 1 pixel border needed

Tags: html, css

I have below result (**Run Code Snippet** Button below), I don't need border around each cell separately I need a simple table like:

[image]

```css
 table td{
    border:1px solid #000000;
 }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Sr No</th>
     <th>Product Name</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Add</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="allign-center">
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA SAFOOF TABKHIR</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA JAWARISH SHAHI AMBRI</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA JAWARISH ZAROONI SADA</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA SAFOOF HAZAM</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `border-collapse: collapse`

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

The border-collapse property sets whether the table borders are collapsed into a single border or detached as in standard HTML.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border:1px solid #69899F;
} 
table td{
    border:1px dotted #000000;
    padding:5px;
}
table td:first-child{
    border-left:0px solid #000000;
}
table th{
   border:2px solid #69899F;
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Sr No</th>
     <th>Product Name</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Add</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="allign-center">
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA SAFOOF TABKHIR</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA JAWARISH SHAHI AMBRI</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA JAWARISH ZAROONI SADA</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA SAFOOF HAZAM</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: good can you please add code snippet with 1 px black border i ask this because your solution is not working on my side

Comment: Glad to help you  :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for. Give it a shot.

```css
 table {
border:1px solid #CCC;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
border:none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Sr No</th>
     <th>Product Name</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Add</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="allign-center">
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA SAFOOF TABKHIR</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA JAWARISH SHAHI AMBRI</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA JAWARISH ZAROONI SADA</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td class="proname">MARHABA SAFOOF HAZAM</td>
     <td><input class="qty" type="number"></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>Add</button></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only table border around:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

**Without space (use for table):**

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td, th {
border: 3px dotted#ddd;
text-align: left;
}

 table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
 }

th, td {
padding: 15px;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>The padding Property</h2>
    <p>This property adds space between the border and the content in a table. </p>

 <table>
 <tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>firstname1</td>
<td>lastname1</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Lois</td>
   <td>Griffin</td>
   <td>$150</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>firstname2</td>
   <td>lastname2</td>
   <td>$300</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>firstname3</td>
      <td>lastname3</td>
      <td>$250</td>
 </tr>
 </table>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do like this,    

<style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1.5px solid rgb(37, 192, 102);
            background-color: antiquewhite;
    
        }
    
        table td {
            border: 1px dotted #121312c7;
    
            padding: 10px;
        }
    
        table td:first-child {
            border-left: 0px solid #000000;
        }
    
        table tr:first-child {
            border: 1.5px solid rgb(37, 192, 102);
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: rgb(37, 192, 102);
    
        }
    
        table th {
            border: 0px solid rgb(37, 192, 102);
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    
    <table style="width: 50%;">
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
            <th>Futured</th>
        </tr>
    
        {% for data in obj %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}.</td>
            <td>{{data.title}}</td>
            <td>{{data.description}}</td>
            <td>{{data.price}}</td>
            <td>{{data.summary}}</td>
            <td>{{data.futured.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```